# query syntax to select every multiple of nn record (shapefile)

Tags: arcgis-10.1, sql

I have data like multiples of 40.
40
80
120
160
200
and so on.

I would like to label every record that is a multiple of 100.  I have tried a couple of methods and can't get them to work either as a query in the label or as a select statement.

```
"STATION" =  %00  
RIGHT ("STATION", 2) =  00
```

[image]

I get invalid SQL statement.
Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Respectfully I did search and did not see any of the example questions you presented.  However it still does not answer my question, re-stated, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your field text or numeric?

Comment: This question has been answered several times (for various versions of software): searching our site should turn up many of those answers.

Comment: my field is numeric

Comment: Here's another solution: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54887/attribute-query-for-first-last-record-and-every-nth-inbetween/54896#54896.  Now that you know 'MOD' is involved, why not search on [MOD SQL](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=mod+sql)?

Comment: Thanks Whuber. I still can't figure out why my like statement doesn't work.

Comment: that solution (54887) only works if your objectids are in the correct geographic order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the MOD function, which returns the remainder after division:

```
MOD("STATION",100) = 0
```

Here's an example, in which I've selected all the records having an ADMINID which is a multiple of 10:

[image]

Comment: This only works if your field is numeric.

Comment: You can use CAST("my_text_field_that_has_numbers" AS NUMERIC) to convert it.